# Trying out AOP in Spring for getting connection from Datasource

Tags: java, spring, spring-aop

here i am trying out AOP using Spring, here the AOP is used for getting Connection from Datasource and closing the connection as well, the code is as follows,

This is the pojo of Student as follows,

```
 package com.database.pojo;
 import org.springframework.context.annotation.Scope;
 import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

 @Component("student01Inj")
 @Scope("prototype")
 public class StudentPOJO {

    private Integer studentId;
    private String studentName;

    public StudentPOJO(){
        System.out.println(this.getClass().getName()+" initialised ....");
    }   

    public StudentPOJO(Integer studentId,String studentName){
        this.studentId = studentId;
        this.studentName = studentName;
    }

    public Integer getStudentId() {
        return studentId;
    }
    public void setStudentId(Integer studentId) {
        this.studentId = studentId;
    }
    public String getStudentName() {
        return studentName;
    }
    public void setStudentName(String studentName) {
        this.studentName = studentName;
    }

 }
```

this is an interface and its implementation where i want to 
place the pointcut method,

Interface StudentPOJOService.java as follows,

```
 package com.database.pojo;
 import java.sql.Connection;
 import java.util.List;

 public interface StudentPOJOService {
    List<StudentPOJO> getStudents(Connection[] connection);
 }
```

Implementation of the above interface as follows,

```
 package com.database.pojo;
 import java.sql.Connection;
 import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
 import java.sql.ResultSet;
 import java.util.ArrayList;
 import java.util.List;
 import org.springframework.context.annotation.Scope;
 import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;


 @Component("student_pojo_ser_inj")
 @Scope("singleton")
 public class StudentPOJOServiceImpl implements StudentPOJOService{ 

    @Override
    public List<StudentPOJO> getStudents(Connection[] objects){
        Connection con = null;
        PreparedStatement pstmt = null;
        ResultSet rs = null;
        List<StudentPOJO>  studentList = null;
        try{
            studentList = new ArrayList<StudentPOJO>();
            con = (objects != null && objects.length >  0) ? objects[0] : null;
            if(con == null){
                System.out.println(" CON NULL ");
            }
            pstmt = con.prepareStatement(" select id,studentName from tblstudent ");
            rs = pstmt.getResultSet();
            while(rs.next()){
                StudentPOJO pojo = new StudentPOJO();
                pojo.setStudentId(rs.getInt("id"));
                pojo.setStudentName(rs.getString("studentName"));
                studentList.add(pojo);
            }
        }catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println(" XXXXX "+e);
        }
        return studentList;
    }
 }
```

this is the AOP related class where i want to invoke methods areound the 
pointcut,

```
 package com.database.aop;
 import java.sql.Connection;
 import java.sql.SQLException;
 import org.aspectj.lang.ProceedingJoinPoint;
 import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Around;
 import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Aspect;
 import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Pointcut;
 import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
 import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;
 import org.springframework.context.annotation.Scope;
 import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource;
 import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

 @Aspect
 @Component("databaseWrapperINJ")
 @Scope("prototype")
 public class DatabaseWrapperEx01 {

    public DatabaseWrapperEx01 (){
        System.out.println(this.getClass().getName()+" intialised ..... ");
    }

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("demoDatasourceInj")
    public DriverManagerDataSource dataSourceManager;

    private Connection con = null; 

    private void setConnection() throws SQLException{
        this.con = this.dataSourceManager.getConnection();
    }

    private void closeConn() throws Exception{
        if(this.con != null && !this.con.isClosed()){
            this.con.close();
        }
    }

    @Pointcut("execution(* com.database.pojo.StudentPOJOService.getStudents(..))")
    public void fetchStudent() throws Throwable{ }

    @Around("fetchStudent()")
    public void methodCallForStudentFetch(ProceedingJoinPoint jointPoint) throws Throwable{
        try{
            this.setConnection();
            jointPoint.proceed(new Connection[] { this.con });
            this.closeConn();
        }catch(Throwable e){
            System.out.println(e);
            this.closeConn();
        }
    }
 }
```

this is the spring-data.xml where all the spring definition goes,

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <beans     xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
        xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"       
        xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"             
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
                            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
                            http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-3.0.xsd">

        <context:annotation-config />
        <context:component-scan  base-package="com.database" />

        <bean   id="demoDatasourceInj"
                class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource"
                p:driverClassName="org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver"
                p:url="jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/sun-appserv-samples"
                p:username="APP"
                p:password="APP" />

        <bean   id="proxyCreator_inj" class="org.springframework.aop.aspectj.annotation.AnnotationAwareAspectJAutoProxyCreator" />
 </beans>
```

The class containing main method which i will be calling from command prompt,

```
 package com.database.main;
 import java.sql.Connection;
 import java.util.List;
 import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
 import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;
 import com.database.pojo.StudentPOJO;
 import com.database.pojo.StudentPOJOService;

 public class Ex02 {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ApplicationContext ctx = null;
        StudentPOJOService service = null;
        List<StudentPOJO> studentList = null;
        Connection[] cons = null;
        try{
            ctx = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("spring-data.xml");
            service = (StudentPOJOService) ctx.getBean("student_pojo_ser_inj");
            studentList = service.getStudents(cons);
            System.out.println("     _ "+studentList.size());
        }catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println(e);
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

 }
```

Now when i try to run the above class i get an exception,

```
[java]  "methodCallForStudentFetch" called
[java]  org.springframework.aop.AopInvocationException: AOP configuration seems to be invalid: tried calling method 
[public abstract java.util.List com.database.pojo.StudentPOJOService.getStudents(java.sql.Connection[])]
on target [com.database.pojo.StudentPOJOServiceImpl@b96751]; 
nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: argument type mismatch
```

Here what i am trying to do is get the connection from datasource in AOP, and than pass the same connection to the getStudents method using the method "proceed" of "joinpoint",
but this gives the exception as shown above,

can any body tell me where i am going wrong,

waiting for the reply,

Comment: First of all: Student is a domain object and those should never be wired by Spring!

Comment: ok, regarding the design i will do some rework, this is just a practise example, but my question is whether my line "jointPoint.proceed(new Connection[] { this.con });" in class DriverManagerDataSource.java, is logical, i want to pass Connection fro point-cut, give me some hint